# Installing gcc 4.4.3 on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: gcc, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 9.04 and need to install gcc 4.4.3. Does anyone know how would I do that?

I can't do it with any other versions except maybe gcc 4.4.x.

Currently ubuntu 9.04 has only 4.3.3 available but that is not sufficient for me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build gcc 4.4.3 from source - http://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Or you can install from jaunty repository - http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/jaunty/gcc

Add in your /etc/apt/sources.list - deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty main

Then

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Answer (score 2):

try `sudo apt-get install gcc=4.4.3`

I'm not sure if that's the exact version, but that's how you specify which version you want.

Comment: It doesn't find that version in Ubuntu 9.04 unfortunately.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` first, if that doesn't do it, add the lucid repo in /etc/apt/sources.list, you should be fine using the sources for lucid in 9.04.

Comment: Here are the sources I've got configured on Lucid, just in case you can't find them: https://gist.github.com/38da4f8afe4c44dec6f5

Answer (score 1):

GCC is not that hard to compile, even if you do the entire bootstrap compile.

Comment: I'm sure it's not but I haven't compiled anything from source yet. Is there no other way?

Comment: `sudo ./configure && make && make install`, now wait an hour or 2 (or more)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

- Updating Ubuntu: come on, it's free, don't keep the old stuff lingering around...
- installing the .deb packages from a later Ubuntu release. I would advise against using the full repository, but it might be you need to go dependency hunting (for the right version of glibc, libstdc++ etc.)